# Split wrapped text into array

Tags: c#, vb.net

I want to split a string into an array at a point where the text wraps for a given width

Suppose this is the string.
I want text width to be 300 :

```
I want to split a string into an array at a point where the text wraps for a given width
```

And use a function, something like this :

`Text.SplitAtWrap(300,Text)`

This is the output i want :

```
(0) I want to split a string into an
(1) array at a point where the text
(2) wraps for a given width
```

Edit:
I would probably have to take the font into account, so probably have to use `Drawing.Graphics`.

Comment: What relationship is there (if any) between 300 and the number of characters on each line?

Comment: no no. 300 is just an example width in pixels

Comment: So you mean to consider Font here when doing this?

Comment: Yes and if it works with `Drawing.Graphics` thats cool too

Comment: You mean want to paint the wrapped text? That is so easy check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/baw6k39s.aspx) out

Comment: I dont want to paint it. I want an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[There is an answer here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3de0fb32-78c4-4258-8924-7e2dedd20921/how-to-break-one-string-into-two-or-more-depending-on-font) (please give credit to whom deserve it)

```
public List<string> GetSubstrings(string toSplit, int maxLength, Graphics graph, Font font)
{
     List<string> substrings = new List<string>();
     string[] words = toSplit.Split(" ".ToCharArray());
     string oneSub = "";
     foreach (string oneWord in words)
     {
        string temp = oneSub + oneWord + " ";

        if (graph.MeasureString( temp, font).Width > maxLength) 
        {
           substrings.Add(oneSub);
           oneSub = oneWord + " ";
        }
        else
           oneSub = temp;
     }
     substrings.Add(oneSub);
     return substrings;
}
```

Basically, your input string  is divided in its component words, then each word is measured using the graphics object and a reference font. If the length of the current word plus the previous words is less than the required length the word is rejoined together. Otherwise the resulting string is added to a list of strings to be returned to the caller.

Comment: This works perfect but when i use any arbitrary string like gibberish `sdfasdfasdfasdfasdfasdf` it exceeds the width. How to tackle that? Normally with WordWrap a string like this is forcefully wrapped.

Comment: As explained in the comments on the referenced link, if you need to handle this edge case then you need to work character by character using the same approach